# EF core 3 не сохраняет объект в базу данных и не выдает никаких ошибок

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Проект ASP NET CORE 3, использую  EF Core 3.1.13.

Есть класс объекта и соответствующая ему таблица в БД:

```
[Table("friend")]
    public partial class Friend
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id_Friend")]
        public long IdFriend { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указана фамилия")]
        [DisplayName("Фамилия")]
        [Column("Family_name", TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указано имя")]
        [DisplayName("Имя")]
        [Column("Name_", TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Отчество")]
        [Column("Patronymic_name", TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string PatronymicName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указана дата рождения")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Column("Date_birth", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? DateBirth { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указан насел. п-т")]
        [DisplayName("Насел. пункт")]
        [Column("City_id")]
        public int? CityId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Округ")]
        [Column("District_id")]
        public int? DistrictId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указана улица")]
        [DisplayName("Улица")]
        [Column("Street_id")]
        public int? StreetId { get; set; }
        [Column("MicroDistrict_id")]
        public int? MicroDistrictId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указан дом")]
        [DisplayName("Дом")]
        [Column("House_id")]
        public int? HouseId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(10)")]
        public string Building { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(10)")]
        public string Apartment { get; set; }
        [MinLength(11)]
        [MaxLength(12)]
        [RegularExpression(@"[+]?[0-9]+"), StringLength(12)]
        [DisplayName("Тел.")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(12)")]
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указан УИК")]
        [Column("Polling_station_id")]
        public int? PollingStationId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Организация")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string Organization { get; set; }
        [Column("FieldActivity_id")]
        public int? FieldActivityId { get; set; }
        [MinLength(11)]
        [MaxLength(12)]
        [RegularExpression(@"[+]?[0-9]+"), StringLength(12)]
        [Column("Phone_number_responsible", TypeName = "varchar(12)")]
        public string PhoneNumberResponsible { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Column("Date_registration_site", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? DateRegistrationSite { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Column("Voting_date", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? VotingDate { get; set; }
        [Column("Voter", TypeName = "TINYINT")]
        public bool Voter { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(500)")]
        public string Adress { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("QRcode")]
        [Column("QRcode", TypeName = "varchar(4500)")]
        public string Qrcode { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Column("User_id")]
        public long? UserId { get; set; }
        [Column("GroupU_id")]
        public int? GroupUId { get; set; }  
        [DisplayName("Населен. п-т")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(CityId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Округ")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(DistrictId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual District District { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Сфера деят-ти")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(FieldActivityId))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Fieldactivity.Friends))]
        public virtual Fieldactivity FieldActivity { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Группа")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(GroupUId))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Groupu.Friends))]
        public virtual Groupu GroupU { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Дом")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(HouseId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual House House { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Микрорайон")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(MicroDistrictId))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Microdistrict.Friends))]
        public virtual Microdistrict MicroDistrict { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Участок")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(PollingStationId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual PollingStation PollingStation { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Улица")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(StreetId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual Street Street { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Агитатор")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
        [InverseProperty("Friends")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

Есть контекст для работы с БД:

```
    public partial class VoterCollectorContext : DbContext
        {
            public VoterCollectorContext()
            {
            }
    
            public VoterCollectorContext(DbContextOptions<VoterCollectorContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {
            }
    
            public virtual DbSet<City> City { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<District> District { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Fieldactivity> Fieldactivity { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Friend> Friend { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Groupsusers> Groupsusers { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Groupu> Groupu { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<House> House { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Microdistrict> Microdistrict { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<PollingStation> PollingStation { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Role> Role { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Street> Street { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    
            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
                {
                    //#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
                    optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=root;database=voterCollector", x => x.ServerVersion("8.0.22-mysql"));
                }
// ...
            }
```

Пытаюсь сохранить объекты класса  Friend, полученные с фронта (не с формы, а считанный с файла), но он не сохраняется и ошибок VS никаких не выдает:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        [Produces("application/json")]
[Authorize(Roles = "admin, user")]
        public class FileApiController : ControllerBase
        {
            private readonly ILogger<FileApiController> _logger;
            private readonly VoterCollectorContext _context;
    
            public FileApiController(VoterCollectorContext context, ILogger<FileApiController> logger)
            {
                _context = context;
                _logger = logger;
            }
    
            [HttpPost("uploadDataFromFile")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDataFromFile([FromBody] FriendDTO[] friendsDTO)
            {
                List<int> notUploadRecords = new List<int>();
    
                for(int i=1; i< friendsDTO.Length; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Friend newFriend = CreateFreand(friendsDTO[i]);
                        _context.Friend.Add(newFriend);
                        
                    }
                    catch {
    
                        notUploadRecords.Add(i + 1);                
                    }
                }
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    
                return Ok(notUploadRecords.ToArray());
            }
    
            public Friend CreateFreand(FriendDTO friendDTO)
            {
                Friend newFriend= new Friend();
    
                User userSave = _context.User.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
                newFriend.UserId = userSave.IdUser;
    
                newFriend.FamilyName = friendDTO.FamilyName.Trim();
                newFriend.Name = friendDTO.Name.Trim();
                newFriend.PatronymicName = friendDTO.PatronymicName.Trim();
                string[] dates = friendDTO.DateBirth.Trim().Split('.');
                DateTime datesBirth = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dates[2]), Convert.ToInt32(dates[1]), Convert.ToInt32(dates[0]));
                newFriend.DateBirth = datesBirth;
                int cityId = _context.City.Where(c => c.Name.Equals(friendDTO.CityName.Trim())).FirstOrDefault().IdCity;
                newFriend.CityId = cityId;
                if (friendDTO.DistrictName!=null && !friendDTO.DistrictName.Trim().Equals("")) {
                    newFriend.DistrictId = _context.District.Where(d => d.Name.Equals(friendDTO.DistrictName.Trim())).FirstOrDefault().IdDistrict;
                }
                int streetId = _context.Street.Where(s => s.Name.Equals(friendDTO.Street.Trim())).FirstOrDefault().IdStreet;
                newFriend.StreetId = streetId;
                if (friendDTO.Microdistrict!= null && !friendDTO.Microdistrict.Trim().Equals("")) {
                    newFriend.MicroDistrictId = _context.Microdistrict.Where(md => md.Name.Equals(friendDTO.Microdistrict.Trim())).FirstOrDefault().IdMicroDistrict;
                }
                int houseId = _context.House.Where(h => h.Name.Equals(friendDTO.House.Trim())).FirstOrDefault().IdHouse;
                newFriend.HouseId = houseId;
                newFriend.Apartment = friendDTO.Apartment.Trim();
                newFriend.Telephone = friendDTO.Telephone.Trim();
                PollingStation pollingStation = _context.PollingStation.Where(p => (p.CityId == cityId && p.StreetId == streetId && p.HouseId == houseId)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (pollingStation!= null)
                {
                    newFriend.PollingStationId = pollingStation.IdPollingStation;
                }
                else if(friendDTO.PollingStationName != null && !friendDTO.PollingStationName.Trim().Equals(""))
                {
                    newFriend.PollingStationId = _context.PollingStation.Where(p => p.Name.Equals(friendDTO.PollingStationName.Trim())).FirstOrDefault().IdPollingStation;
                }
                newFriend.Organization = friendDTO.Organization.Trim();
                newFriend.FieldActivityId = _context.Fieldactivity.Where(f => f.Name.Equals(friendDTO.FieldActivityName.Trim())).FirstOrDefault().IdFieldActivity;
                newFriend.PhoneNumberResponsible = friendDTO.PhoneNumberResponsible.Trim();
                if (friendDTO.DateBirth != null && !friendDTO.DateBirth.Trim().Equals(""))
                {
                    string[] datesR = friendDTO.DateRegistrationSite.Trim().Split('.');
                    DateTime datesRegistration = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(datesR[2]), Convert.ToInt32(datesR[1]), Convert.ToInt32(datesR[0]));
                    newFriend.DateRegistrationSite = datesRegistration;
                }
                if (friendDTO.VotingDate != null && !friendDTO.VotingDate.Trim().Equals(""))
                {
                    string[] datesV = friendDTO.VotingDate.Trim().Split('.');
                    DateTime datesVoting = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(datesV[2]), Convert.ToInt32(datesV[1]), Convert.ToInt32(datesV[0]));
                    newFriend.VotingDate = datesVoting;
                }
                newFriend.Description = friendDTO.Description;
                newFriend.GroupUId = _context.Groupu.Where(g => g.Name.Equals(friendDTO.Group.Trim())).FirstOrDefault().IdGroup;
    
                if (friendDTO.Vote != null && !friendDTO.Vote.Trim().Equals(""))
                {
                    newFriend.Voter = friendDTO.Vote.ToLower().Trim().Equals("да") ? true : false;
                }
    
                return newFriend;
            }
            
        }
```

Сам объект создается нормально, добавляется вроде тоже, но на строке:

```
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

просто все прерывается.

Пробовал добавлять объект в контекст 2-мя разными способами:

```
_context.Friend.Add(newFriend);
_context.Add(newFriend);
```

это не помогло.

При этом стандартный MVC-контроллер объекты данного класса сохраняет нормально:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin, user")]
    public class FriendsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<FriendsController> _logger;
        private readonly VoterCollectorContext _context;
        private ServiceUser _serviceUser;

        public FriendsController(VoterCollectorContext context, ILogger<FriendsController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
            _serviceUser = new ServiceUser(context);
        }
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("IdFriend,FamilyName,Name,PatronymicName,DateBirth,CityId,DistrictId,StreetId,MicroDistrictId,HouseId,Building,Apartment,Telephone,PollingStationId,Organization,FieldActivityId,PhoneNumberResponsible,DateRegistrationSite,VotingDate,Voter,Adress,Qrcode,Description,UserId,GroupUId")] Friend friend)
        {
            List<Friend> searchFriend = _context.Friend.Where(frnd => frnd.Name.Equals(friend.Name) && frnd.FamilyName.Equals(friend.FamilyName) && frnd.PatronymicName.Equals(friend.PatronymicName) && frnd.DateBirth.Value.Date == friend.DateBirth.Value.Date).ToList();

            if (searchFriend.Count == 0)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    User userSave = _context.User.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
                    friend.UserId = userSave.IdUser;
                    //friend.GroupUId = userSave.Groupsusers.First().GroupUId;

                    _context.Add(friend);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }

                List<Groupu> groupsUser = _serviceUser.GetGroupsUser(User.Identity.Name);

                ViewData["GroupUId"] = new SelectList(_serviceUser.FilterGroups(groupsUser), "IdGroup", "Name", friend.GroupUId);
                ViewData["CityId"] = new SelectList(_context.City, "IdCity", "Name", friend.CityId);
                ViewData["DistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.District, "IdDistrict", "Name", friend.DistrictId);
                ViewData["FieldActivityId"] = new SelectList(_context.Fieldactivity, "IdFieldActivity", "Name", friend.FieldActivityId);
                ViewData["StreetId"] = new SelectList(_context.Street, "IdStreet", "Name", friend.StreetId);
                ViewData["HouseId"] = new SelectList(_context.House, "IdHouse", "Name", friend.HouseId);
                ViewData["MicroDistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.Microdistrict, "IdMicroDistrict", "Name", friend.MicroDistrictId);
                ViewData["PollingStationId"] = new SelectList(_context.PollingStation, "IdPollingStation", "Name", friend.PollingStationId);
                ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.User, "IdUser", "FamilyName", friend.UserId);
                return View(friend);
            }
            else return Content("Данный пользователь уже был внесен в списки ранее!");
        }
```

Заголовки запросов:

```
General
Request URL: http://localhost:18246/api/FileApi/uploadDataFromFile
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: [::1]:18246
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Mon, 05 Jul 2021 12:48:02 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: Вы ответ на запрос-то посмотрите, если была ошибка - она там должна отобразиться. Ну и логи гляньте. И вообще не забывайте что вы можете написать try/catch и исключение перехватить для изучения.

Comment: Да, похоже ошибки то никак не обрабатываются. Зачем вам `_logger`, если вы в него ничего не пишете? Оберните в `try/catch` и пишите ошибку в логгер, наверняка она там есть.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, спасибо, я нашел проблему в Response

Comment: @CrazyElf, да вы правы, можете в ответе показать на моем примере как правильно связать loger and try/catch, чтобы он выводил ошибку

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir Мне лениво, напишите свой ответ, если разобрались, я плюсану )  Напишите и код и какой эксепшен обнаружили, интересно же

Comment: @CrazyElf, я не знаю как правильно увязать loger и try/catch, поэтому и прошу показать в ответе, это было бы решением )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно проверять не будет ли выброшено исключение при записи в БД и записывать его в лог в этом случае. Примерно так:

```
try
{
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok(notUploadRecords.ToArray());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Error().Exception(ex).Message("Ошибка записи в БД").Write();
    // и нужно вернуть какую-то ошибку, но я не очень понимаю какую в данном случае
    return Problem();
}
```

Comment: Дополнительный вопрос по схожей проблеме: для записи в единичных экземпляров сущностей использую SaveChangesAsync. С MySQL всё ок, с PostgreSQL возникает следующая проблема - периодически (редко) сущности не записываются, а остаются висеть с заголовком в web-интерфейсе постгреса: "idle in transaction (aborted)" с телом: INSERT INTO sometable (fk_name1, fk_name2, message, fk_name3, value, prevvalue, time, fk_name4) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING id

Comment: - висит на простом запросе - а дальше эффект лавины, подобные запросы - просто тупо копятся пока не достигнут лимита, и только после перезапуска программы использующей EFCore они исчезают. Есть предположения почему такие простые запросы висят?

Comment: К сожалению, я с постгресом совсем не работал. А у вас в один поток запросы к этой части кода идут или много потоков? Не очень понимаю как тут будет разруливаться в много потоков, и вообще я по веб программированию не очень разбираюсь ещё.

Comment: Вёба нет, потоков много, у каждого потока свой контекст, другие потоки могут добавлять задачи в ConcurrentQueue, если ранний поток успел освободится (вызвал SaveChangesAsync без await) - он берёт из ConcurrentQueue новую задачу и добавляет её в свой конктекст и так-же вызывает SaveChangesAsync. Т.е. в одном потоке могут часто вызываться SaveChangesAsync без await. Сразу после SaveChangesAsync добавляется ContinueWith. Когда очередь пустеет - вызывается context.DisposeAsync и всё это в void функции. С MySQL всё это великолепно работает, с PostgreSQL обязательно случится затык...